# What is the efficient way to read big tables in pandas Python?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a table in MySql of shape 40 million rows x 54 Columns. I tried reading the table in chunks using read_sql but it goes out of memory (I am working with 32 gb, 8 Core EC2 instance). Then I tried Limit and Offset method but it is really slow.

Is there any efficient way to read the table without losing memory and reading the table faster.

I looked into some Big Data techniques but since I am not familiar with Big Data I am not able to decide which one to go for.

Currently I am using this to read tables but it is really slow and certainly not very efficient.

```
def read_sql_chunked(query, con, nrows, chunksize=10000):
    start = 1
    dfs = []
    while start < nrows:
        df = pd.read_sql("%s LIMIT %s OFFSET %s" % (query, chunksize, start), con)
        dfs.append(df)
        print(start, chunksize)
        start += chunksize
    return pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
dt = read_sql_chunked(query=query, con=conn, nrows=40000000)
```

Comment: Please don't use Indian words here. As you can see, people don't know what are "crore rows".

Answer (score 0):

How may rows does your table have? Sounds like that your table is just too big to fit in the amount of memory that you have. If you want to sumarize the data, you are probably better off doing that in sql first.

Comment: 4crore rows. I don't want to summarize it, I want to use them all for some project.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck No I don't have any SSD or NVME devices. Also this might work but I have 10 such tables and I don't think this is a good approach coding wise. I am looking for a coding solution.

Comment: @ParitoshSharma Coding solution can not cover configuration errors.  Please provide information requested 2020-06-02 and SHOW CREATE TABLE (one of the 10 tables that are similar); , thanks.

Comment: @ParitoshSharma Your problem could be as simple as needing indexes to prevent table scanning.  Please provide the B) C) D) F) G) from your system via pastebin.com or similar text sharing facility.